# convert local dateTime to UTC in R

Tags: r, datetime, local, utc

How can I convert local DateTime in the following format `"12/31/2014 6:42:52 PM"` to UTC in R? I tried this

`as.POSIXct(as.Date("12/31/2014 6:42:52 PM", format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"),tz="UTC")`

but it doesn't seem to be valid.

Comment: did you try `strptime("12/31/2014 6:42:52 PM", format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S",tz="UTC")` ?

Comment: What is your current timezone in R console, type `Sys.timezone()`

Comment: `as.POSIXct("12/31/2014 6:42:52 PM", format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S",tz="UTC")` - drop the `as.Date()` part in the middle. It's not needed and it just means you cut the time component, stuffing up the conversion. @MamounBenghezal 's answer also returns a `POSIXlt` instead of a `POSIXct` date/time. Use `as.POSIXct` in preference as it is generally more adaptable.

Comment: Please note that I need to convert "12/31/2014 6:42:52 PM" which is local DateTime to UTC.

Comment: As presented, your date and time are at the same time local time and UTC.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you want to shift a datetime from your current timezone to UTC, you need to 
import in your local timezone, then just shift the display timezone to "UTC". e.g.: in Australian EST I am UTC+10.

```
out <- as.POSIXct("12/31/2014 6:42:52 PM", format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
out
#"2014-12-31 06:42:52 EST"
#(Australian Eastern Standard Time)
as.numeric(out)
#[1] 1419972172
```

Now shift the timezone for display purposes:

```
attr(out, "tzone") <- "UTC" 
out
#[1] "2014-12-30 20:42:52 UTC" 
# display goes 10 hours backwards as I'm UTC+10
as.numeric(out)
#[1] 1419972172
```

Note that this doesn't affect the underlying numeric data (seconds since 1970-01-01), it only changes what is displayed.