# Handle daylight savings using as.POSIXct() or functions in the lubridate package

Tags: r, datetime, posix, lubridate, dst

Suppose I have given this vector `x`. I want to convert these to `"America/Detroit"` time zone.

```
x <- c("2018-03-10 23:30:00", "2018-03-11 00:00:00", "2018-03-11 00:30:00", "2018-03-11 01:00:00",
       "2018-03-11 01:30:00", "2018-03-11 02:00:00", "2018-03-11 02:30:00",
       "2018-03-11 03:00:00",
       "2018-03-11 03:30:00", "2018-03-11 04:00:00", "2018-03-11 04:30:00")
```

If I use `ymd_hms()` as follows I get two `NA` because of DST.

```
ymd_hms(x, tz = "America/Detroit")
 [1] "2018-03-10 23:30:00 EST" "2018-03-11 00:00:00 EST" "2018-03-11 00:30:00 EST"
 [4] "2018-03-11 01:00:00 EST" "2018-03-11 01:30:00 EST" NA                       
 [7] NA                        "2018-03-11 03:00:00 EDT" "2018-03-11 03:30:00 EDT"
[10] "2018-03-11 04:00:00 EDT" "2018-03-11 04:30:00 EDT"
Warning message:
 2 failed to parse.
```

Is there a way to format `x` to date-time such that everything after "2018-03-11 02:00:00" rolls forward by one hour? The final date-times should look as follows:

```
c("2018-03-10 23:30:00 EST", "2018-03-11 00:00:00 EST", "2018-03-11 00:30:00 EST", "2018-03-11 01:00:00 EST",
  "2018-03-11 01:30:00 EST", "2018-03-11 03:00:00 EDT", "2018-03-11 03:30:00 EDT",
  "2018-03-11 04:00:00 EDT", "2018-03-11 04:30:00 EDT", "2018-03-11 05:00:00 EDT", "2018-03-11 05:30:00 EDT")
```

If I use `force_tz()`, it doesn't do what I want.

```
force_tz(ymd_hms(x), tz="America/Detroit", roll = TRUE)
 [1] "2018-03-10 23:30:00 EST" "2018-03-11 00:00:00 EST" "2018-03-11 00:30:00 EST"
 [4] "2018-03-11 01:00:00 EST" "2018-03-11 01:30:00 EST" "2018-03-11 03:00:00 EDT"
 [7] "2018-03-11 03:00:00 EDT" "2018-03-11 03:00:00 EDT" "2018-03-11 03:30:00 EDT"
[10] "2018-03-11 04:00:00 EDT" "2018-03-11 04:30:00 EDT"
```

Comment: For analysis like this on timeseries, i'd strongly suggest using a timesone without DST (like UTC time)

Comment: See this post how to do convert to UTC: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29687704/6574038

Comment: @Wimpel This is to visualize the data. I want to show the DST gap.

Comment: @jay.sf I am not sure how this link is helpful to get what I want here.

Comment: The link is meant in connection with @Wimpel's comment above.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell what timezone your data is, from your explanation and desired output it seems you have all times in EST (Eastern Standard Time).

Also note the difference between `force_tz` and `with_tz`

`force_tz` keeps the time the same but alters the timezone, this results in non-existing times for that set timezone.

`with_tz` you use when you want to convert times from one to another (tell me how late it is here versus somewhere else).

So we take your EST timezone and convert that to the times of "America/Detroit" which includes both EST and EDT times

**solution**

```
x <- c("2018-03-10 23:30:00", "2018-03-11 00:00:00", "2018-03-11 00:30:00", "2018-03-11 01:00:00", "2018-03-11 01:30:00", "2018-03-11 02:00:00", "2018-03-11 02:30:00", "2018-03-11 03:00:00", "2018-03-11 03:30:00", "2018-03-11 04:00:00", "2018-03-11 04:30:00")

x <- ymd_hms(x, tz = "EST") # here we tell all dates we have are in EST

with_tz(x, "America/Detroit")

[1] "2018-03-10 23:30:00 EST" "2018-03-11 00:00:00 EST" "2018-03-11 00:30:00 EST" "2018-03-11 01:00:00 EST" "2018-03-11 01:30:00 EST" "2018-03-11 03:00:00 EDT" "2018-03-11 03:30:00 EDT"
 [8] "2018-03-11 04:00:00 EDT" "2018-03-11 04:30:00 EDT" "2018-03-11 05:00:00 EDT" "2018-03-11 05:30:00 EDT"
```

Compare that to

```
force_tz(x, "America/Detroit", roll = T)

 [1] "2018-03-10 23:30:00 EST" "2018-03-11 00:00:00 EST" "2018-03-11 00:30:00 EST" "2018-03-11 01:00:00 EST" "2018-03-11 01:30:00 EST" "2018-03-11 03:00:00 EDT" "2018-03-11 03:00:00 EDT"
 [8] "2018-03-11 03:00:00 EDT" "2018-03-11 03:30:00 EDT" "2018-03-11 04:00:00 EDT" "2018-03-11 04:30:00 EDT"
```